# `trap n condition` syntax

Tags: shell, trap

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap :

> trap n [condition...] trap [action condition...]
>
> If the first operand is an unsigned decimal integer, the shell shall
>   treat all operands as conditions, and shall reset each condition to
>   the default value. Otherwise, if there are operands, the first is
>   treated as an action and the remaining as conditions.
>
> If action is '-', the shell shall reset each condition to the default
>   value.

What is the `trap n` syntax for? Isn't it basically the same things as `trap -`?

Comment: Likely for Bourne shell compatibility. Bourne shell didn't support the `-` action. To reset traps, the [man page](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man1/sh.1) just said to omit the action.